# How to avoid overwriting routes in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-6

Sorry in advance, I know it has been asked before but I did not figure out the solution.

I am new to Laravel, still learning and stuck with this issue:

My objective is to add pages in admin and show these pages in frontend.

For the Front part of the website I have this route:

```
Route::get('/{page}', 'PagesController@show');
```

- so the when you access /about, /contact, /another-page I use the same view

For the Admin part of the website I have this route:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@show');
```

My problem is that the first route overwrites the second route and I don't know how to avoid this.

I have tried with [namespaces and grouping routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-groups), but I get the same outcome.

Thank you

Comment: Switch their orders in the routes file. I can't remember if the first one overrides the second or the other way around, but swap it and it should work.

Comment: give your route a name and it will give you the error when the same name written for more about same https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes

Comment: @ceejayoz I will give it a try

Comment: @ceejayoz I just made a fresh install and swapped routes order and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it simple this is happening because you have the route with the parameter before the admin route so is going to send the "admin as a parameter of page"

The Simple fix is just put admin route before your "/{page} so it will find admin route first,Something Like this:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@show');
Route::get('/{page}', 'PagesController@show');
```

But I do not recommend building your routes this way and have specifics pages setup if possible, This way of building routes will mess around with the 404 route not found aswell.

Comment: I do recommend reading about laravel routes and learning names etc to do things properly.

Comment: Hi @TheLacrox, I already tried with names, but it did not work (got the same results). I have to make a fresh install and start again because nothing is working anymore with all my tests. I will try your method and come back again. Is there a guide somewhere on how to organize routes when creating custom CMS?